# What is this error in spring mvc integrated via memcache

Tags: java, spring-mvc, caching, memcached, simple-spring-memcached

I want to use simple-spring-memcached to cache data. so using this https://code.google.com/p/simple-spring-memcached/wiki/Getting_Started for my purpose.
i add in my dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
  <aop:aspectj-autoproxy />
  <import resource="simplesm-context.xml" /> 
  <bean name="cacheManager" class="com.google.code.ssm.spring.SSMCacheManager">
    <property name="caches">
        <set>
            <bean class="com.google.code.ssm.spring.SSMCache">
                <constructor-arg name="cache" index="0" ref="defaultCache"/>
                <!-- 5 minutes -->
                <constructor-arg name="expiration" index="1" value="0"/>
                <!-- @CacheEvict(..., "allEntries" = true) doesn't work -->
                <constructor-arg name="allowClear" index="2" value="false"/>
            </bean>
        </set>
    </property>

</bean>
<bean name="defaultCache" class="com.google.code.ssm.CacheFactory">
    <property name="cacheName" value="defaultCache"/>
    <property name="cacheClientFactory">
        <bean name="cacheClientFactory"  class="com.google.code.ssm.providers.xmemcached.MemcacheClientFactoryImpl"/>
    </property>
    <property name="addressProvider">
        <bean class="com.google.code.ssm.config.DefaultAddressProvider">
            <property name="address" value="127.0.0.1:11211"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="configuration">
        <bean class="com.google.code.ssm.providers.CacheConfiguration">
            <property name="consistentHashing" value="true"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
  </bean>
```

i also add simple-spring-memcached-3.5.0.jar and spymemcache.jar,spymemcache-provider.jar to lib folder. but when i run my project occur this exception:

```
 Cannot find class **[net.nelz.simplesm.config.MemcachedClientFactory]** for bean with name 'memcachedClientFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/simplesm-context.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.nelz.simplesm.config.MemcachedClientFactory
```

Answer (score 1):

you must add lib for this class.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: because my reputation is low.

Comment: I think you can give comments to answer now.

Answer (score 0):

It seams that you have also an old version of Simple Spring Memcached on your classpath. The class `net.nelz.simplesm.config.MemcachedClientFactory` is no longer available in 3.x. Check your classpath and remove all Simple Spring Memcached artifacts older than 3.5.0.

Comment: i remove all simple-spring-memcached older than 3.5.0. but the exception occur yet. Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [net.nelz.simplesm.config.MemcachedClientFactory] for bean with name 'memcachedClientFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/simplesm-context.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.nelz.simplesm.config.MemcachedClientFactory

Comment: what is simplesm-context.xml and why use it?

Comment: `simplesm-context.xml` contains definition of beans used by Simple Spring Memcached. For some reason in your case it points to some old simplesm-context.xml (from version 1.x or 2.x). Check your classpath and make sure that the file is only available in `simple-spring-memcached-3.5.0.jar`

Comment: i remove all ssm older than 3.5.0. my lib folder is: http://www.uploadimage.ro/img.php?image=2079_222_b35x.png

Comment: I assume that your application is distributed as a war. If so then unpack content of the war and use OS tool to find `simplesm-context.xml` file in the unpacked directory. Make sure that the tool will search also all archives (jar files). Maybe you have copied the file into your `WEB-INF` folder ?

Comment: i unpack it. http://www.uploadimage.ro/img.php?image=7744_unpak_dxar.png but not fount com.google.code.ssm.spring.SSMCacheManager
in it.why?

Comment: i add this jar file to lib xmemcached-provider-3.1.0.jar,xmemcached-2.0.0.jar, spring-cache-3.0.2.jar and not occur any excption. but i think caching not work. why?

Comment: The `SSMCacheManager` is in spring-cache-3.5.0.jar (it is SSM jar not Spring), [here](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/code/simple-spring-memcached/spring-cache/3.5.0/spring-cache-3.5.0.jar) you can find it. Use maven to manage your dependencies. Use the latest SSM version 3.5.0